# Global Variable not refreshing in Simulink

Tags: matlab, global-variables, simulink

I'm not very familiar with Simulink, but I need it for an experimental setup I am building, so I'm learning as I go.

I am using Simulink to send signals to different pieces of hardware. In my Simulink code, I have set a global variable called temp (red *) that is used in a MatLab function (blue *). This Simulink code is based on a previous code from a colleague, and the "Data Store Memory" box was not connected to anything in the original code.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the inside of "Data Store Memory." In the original code, though, it says it's connected to a function Write Angle1 which I repurposed into Write Angle2. You can see this from an older version of my code in the third image.

[image]
[image: image2]

My colleague told me that if I click refresh, it should automatically update the code that uses `temp`, which is the blue star in the first image, but this isn't working.

Here is the beginning of my Write angle2 code from Simulink. Write now the temp is being called, and I have not incorporated it later in the code at the moment, but when I did briefly and then went back to Simulink and clicked refresh, but this still did not work. I'm hoping to get to the bottom of the problem, and if the problem isn't clear, I'll be happy to edit the question to provide additional information.

```
function [y,P] = fcn(Initial,Times,t,crc_table,Ini_phi)
    clc
    %#codegen
    global temp
    sample = 0.005;
    tt = double(t)/double(sample);
    tt = round(tt);
    f = 0.999;      % 99.9% of a value to be compared to
```

My goal is to make sure that "Data Store Memory" communicates the global variable temp with Write angle2.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to link it to the function because there is no "Data Store Write" block used at the output of your MATLAB function "Write Angle 2".

It will be pretty clear with this screenshot:
[Data Store blocks screensot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl0H5.png)

I suggest using the following steps to make Data Store connections:

1. Add "Data Store Memory" block, open it and add a Data Store Name.
2. Add "Data Store Write" block, open it and start typing the same name, it will automatically list the Data Store Name, just click on it and the connection is made.

Comment: I'll try that. But my colleague did not need that when he was using a similar Simulink code.